# How to completely rename a project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

The old project name was expense_calculator. 
Then I renamed the project to a different name, but somewere the old name still present, so when I import a package in Android Studio it substitutes the old name in imports, like

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:downloads_path_provider/downloads_path_provider.dart';
import 'package:expensecalculator/models/entry.dart';
import 'package:expensecalculator/models/entry_list_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
...
```

How can I change all of the names throughout the whole project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the package `name` parameter in the `pubspec.yaml` file to whatever new name you want. Then the imports will use the new name.